# How do I get API credentials (user authentication and service principal authentication) for Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am wanting to write some code to access Microsoft Azure. I've dug extensively through the management console but it's still not clear how I generate credentials to access the APIs.

I have searched the console but I am lost.

Two methods are shown in the below code to get credentials. It would be great if someone could explain step-by-step **how to get credentials using each of these methods  (user authentication and service principal authentication)**.

The following code is from this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/issues/1606#issuecomment-181405138

```
var msrestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');
 //user authentication
 var credentials = new msRestAzure.UserTokenCredentials('your-client-id', 'your-domain', 'your-username', 'your-password', 'your-redirect-uri');
 //service principal authentication
 var credentials = new msRestAzure.ApplicationTokenCredentials('your-client-id', 'your-domain', 'your-secret');
```

Comment: If you are hosting a Web API on azure and if you're using Azure AD as your authority you can take advantage of a few different authentication scenarios.  From client-side (web) code or from a native app you should use OAuth and use a Bearer Token -- more info: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-devquickstarts-webapi-dotnet/

Comment: I am trying to start and stop virtual machines using the computemanagement SDK.